# iPad screen recording stopped working

Tags: error, quicktime, screen-capture

I frequently record my iPad (mini 2) screen with Quicktime. Has always worked just fine. 
Now suddenly I get the error message "The operation could not be completed" everytime I try it. It appears the iPad disconnects from the Mac as soon as I select it as a source in quicktime. 
It works fine with my iPhone, so it seems to be a problem with the iPad. 
I tried different cables, rebooting all devices, and even reset my iPad. Still the same. Any idea what else I could do?

Comment: What version of iOS and macOS are you using? ([edit] your question)

Comment: I have the same problem on macOS 10.12.4 and iOS 10.3.1